# Why row tuples are immutable in Postgres

Tags: linux, postgresql

I came across very interesting article: https://eng.uber.com/mysql-migration/, I haven't known that postgres has immutable tuples and adds new ones after each update. What is reason of this decision?
PS. Are old, not active tuples deleted after some time?

Answer (score 3):

You should really read the excellent PostgreSQL documentation if you want to understand this.

The design idea behind this is that PostgreSQL wants to provide multiversioning (keep around old versions of a tuple to avoid having to block readers while an update is in progress) to improve concurrency while not burdening the writers with the associated burden (cleanup of old versions, undo work in case of rollback).

To facilitate this, the *autovacuum* daemon regularly scans active tables to free the space used up by tuples that are no longer needed by anybody.

While this approach certainly also has its drawbacks (most notably the danger of table bloat if autovacuum cannot keep up), it avoids the unpleasantries of maintaining "rollback" or "undo" data structures that databases like Oracle or InnoDB have (lots of work rolling back long transactions, unpredictable "snapshot too old" errors).